# memory leak in com.opensymphony.xwork2

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

Trying to detect memory leak in an application. Looked into the tomcat logs.
Tomcat detects that the leaks are from `com.opensymphony.xwork2.*` api.

I just want to know if this can be the reason for the crash?

Below is the log that claims a leak.

```
SEVERE: The web application [/openreports] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@1bfdfa36]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@3f35fd95]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
SEVERE: The web application [/openreports] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@7edb7d08]) and a value of type [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory] (value [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory@7bedd948]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
SEVERE: The web application [/openreports] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@6d041bf8]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext[]] (value [[Lcom.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext;@3c544588]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```